# Updating table depending on dynamic keys of object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here myObject is an object and I want to update my table depending upon the **number of keys myObject contains**.
The number of keys in myObject can be dynamic how do I update the table in that case?

```
var myObject ={
   x1 : 0,
   x2 :1
}

var stmt =""UPDATE tb_data SET x1 = ?, x2 = ?....xn =?";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Object.keys(myObject).forEach to loop through each of your objects, building up the string you need each time.

```
var myObject ={
       x1 : 0,
       x2 :1
    }

    var stmnt = '';

    Object.keys(myObject).forEach((val) => {
      stmnt += val;
    })
```

Comment: UPDATE tb_data SET x1 = ?, x2 = ?, How to remove this extra comma at end of last key @jsw324

Comment: You just need to build up your string however you want it to look. For your example, i'd use something like this `var stmnt = 'UPDATE tb_data ';

Object.keys(myObject).forEach((val) => {
  stmnt += val + ': ' + myObject[val] + ' ';
})
`

Comment: @AryanKanwar If this answer helped, please mark it as correct.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Improving on jsw324's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43632957/7925282)

```
var myObject ={
   x1 : 0,
   x2 :1
}

let stmt ='UPDATE tb_data SET ';

Object.keys(myObject).forEach((key)=>{
    const val = myObject[key];
    stmt += `${key} = ${val}, `;
})

stmt = stmt.splitOnLast(',')[0]+';'
//Stmt = "UPDATE tb_data SET x1=0, x2=1;"
```